# Dependent Dropdown lists and Offset formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with a price list for many items, all of them have a column for category and another column for core product, secondary or third. I then have description, price etc.
I have built an Invoice configurator that when the user selects a category it comes up with an offset formula for product (description) and a bloom up formula then brings up the item code, price etc.

I have an issue where I am trying to get the spreadsheet to allow me to have the following.
 1. Dropdown for product type.
 2. Dependent Dropdown for category
 3. Dependent Dropdown for product type
 4. Then the offset formula to look at all 3 Dropdown options and only provide me with those products.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide at least a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dependant dropdown menus with named ranges, data validation and `INDIRECT` formula. Then use `FILTER` formula to extract the products corresponding to the 3 selected options. I've made a tiny example :

[image: Drop]

With blue background, the dropodown menus (2 dependants). On the right, the named ranges. On top, the data. With green background, the output (1 result only since my sample DATA is very small).

EDIT : You want a dropdown menu to select the results (after the user has done his 3 choices). You can use `TEXTJOIN` to build a list from the results and then create another dropdown menu (dynamically resized). If you want something more "transparent" (no table of results to hide), it's possible to replace the `FILTER` formula with `SUMPRODUCT` and `MATCH` (the `TEXTJOIN` column will be placed in the original table and might cause slowdowns if the number of items is too big).

[image: Drop2]

[Sheet](https://covid19.framadrop.org/lufi/r/AxYyEYHwUT#D1CzTF/xFLtuznMl8BY+1HBU7n8dDc6ed+JZ4F9kDws=)

Comment: Thank you @E.Wiest I have used your example and put it in to practice. I have an issue where I have multiple products, for example, where you have 'Bookcases' & 'PAB' & 'CORE' there might be 5, and I want the output to be a dropdown for the user to select the one they want. Do you know of a way of putting this formula in to a dropdown allowing the user to select from the list it populate? (Formula I have = =IF(H19="IWA",FILTER(IWA!F1:F4979,(IWA!C1:C4979=I19)*(IWA!B1:B4979=J19)),IF(H19="IWK",FILTER(IWK!F1:F4979,(IWK!C1:C4979=I19)*(IWK!B1:B4979=J19)),""))

Comment: Brilliant, this has worked for what I require, thank you so much